# Django REST Framework - How to create an Order?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am new at **Django REST API**, and my project has two models:

```
Product (id, name, value)

Order(id, client_name, product: ManyToMany(Product))
```

How can i create and order using the **POST** method?

Comment: use Django documentation and maybe a bit of coding SO is for SOLVING errors not giving you the whole code buddy.

Comment: The [Django REST Framework Tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) is pretty good and will answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use post method easily. But there are types of view like ClassBasedView, FunctionBasedView etc. But ClassBasedView is easy to use as well as we can understand it in a better way. But first you go to documentation and understand the flow. Let see ClassBasedview.
You can create post method like this:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

It is not tough to create an Order. I hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: @user8573812 if Product has one more field (quantity) how can I decrease it when user orders it?